# Is regularization in machine learning and deep learning same

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

As there are L1 , L2 , etc out and other technique are those all same for machine learning and deep learning while using Ml algorithm and DL algorithm

Comment: What are your findings so far? What is your understanding of ML/DL? Do you know what L1 and L2 are?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: ML and DL are the same thing,

Answer (score 1):

Yes L1 and L2 in DL and ML refers to the same kind of regularization. DL can also benefit from dropout which is an additional method of regularization. See [this article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/fundamentals-deep-learning-regularization-techniques/).